# Защита от Self-XSS

Tags: javascript, безопасность, xss

Есть ли какие-нибудь защитные алгоритмы от этой атаки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Self-XSS** - один из видов социальной инженерии, при котором словами от жертвы добиваются того, что он/она самостоятельно выполняет вредоносный javascript-код, путем его копирования в адресную строку или консоль разработчика.

Бороться можно пробовать только путем инструктажа пользователей. Наподобие:

> Дорогие пользователи!
>
> Пожалуйста не верьте личным сообщениям, сулящим смерть вашему любимому актеру, ежели вы немедленно не скопируете в адресную нижеприведенный код, и не нажмете enter.

По другому - никак. Это психология - техническими средствами уж точно тут не поможешь.